# Bluetooth switch not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: bluetooth, 22.04, asus, bluez

Installed brand new Ubuntu 22.04 on my Asus machine and Bluetooth switch toggle is not working.

Output of `sudo systemctl status bluetooth.service`:

[image]

Output of `rfkill list`:

[image]

Screenshot of Bluetooth settings:

[image]

```
0000:57:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. Device [14c3:7922]
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: AzureWave Device [1a3b:5300]
    Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 13d3:5460 IMC Networks USB2.0 HD UVC WebCam
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 04f3:0c6e Elan Microelectronics Corp. ELAN:Fingerprint
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c548 Logitech, Inc. USB Receiver
Bus 003 Device 010: ID 0e6a:02c0 Megawin Technology Co., Ltd Defender Gaming Keyboard
Bus 003 Device 009: ID 25a4:9311 USB C   USB C Video Adaptor      
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 093a:2530 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Gaming Mouse
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
```

```
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 003 Device 008: ID 13d3:3568 IMC Networks Wireless_Device
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0bda:8153 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8153 Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 2109:0817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB3.0 Hub             
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
[    8.592620] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    8.592895] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    8.592900] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    8.592916] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    8.592925] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    8.592941 Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
    8.604608 rtk_btusb: Realtek Bluetooth USB driver ver 3.1.244af65.20200806-165553
 21.778557 Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
   21.778563 Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
   21.778570 Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list; lsusb; sudo dmesg | grep -i blue` terminal command. Please post it as text, not as a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Bluetooth device is not supported by Ubuntu kernels yet.

You need to install a  mainline 6.0+ kernel to get it working.